# Unable to connect to youtube or gmail using IE or Edge

Tags: networking, windows-10, troubleshooting

Internet Explorer or MS Edge Browsers won't connect to YouGube or Gmail.  However I can connect using Chrome or Firefox.

When attempting to use the Windows 10 network troubleshooter to connect to YouTube or Gmail I get the following error.

```
Windows could not automatically detect this network's proxy settings.
```

What else should I be looking at to fix this?

**Update:** I am not using a proxy.  The only security in use is Windows Defender.  There are no certificate errors on the browser.  F12 Developer tools shows only a warning "`Current window: microsoft.microsoftedge/assets/errorpages/dnserror.html`"

Thanks

Comment: Are you using proxy?  If you are, you should modify your question, and mention that fact.

Comment: Are you using any security software, currently configured, to scan secure traffic.  If you are you should disable that feature, and verify, your still unable to navigate to these sites in questions.  What certificate errors exists in (IE,Chrome, Firefox) if any do exist.  Update your question in order to provide this information.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have too many custom security levels for applications/websites you can always reset your Internet options back to default. Sometimes these options get corrupted/confused and resetting them will restore access.

In Internet Explorer go to Internet Options and then the advanced tab. Hit the reset button in the bottom.

**This will erase any changes made to Internet Explorer restoring it back to its default state**

[image]